# Anaconda Command Prompt Window Won't Open After Reinstallation

Tags: anaconda, command-prompt, miniconda

I have had to uninstall and then reinstall miniconda. After reinstalling, when I run, the powershell prompt shows the following message:

```
& : The term 'C:\Users\jenj0\anaconda3\Scripts\conda.exe' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script
file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct
and try again.
At C:\Users\jenj0\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\profile.ps1:4 char:4
+ (& "C:\Users\jenj0\anaconda3\Scripts\conda.exe" "shell.powershell" "h ...
+    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\Users\jenj0\...ripts\conda.exe:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

(base) PS C:\Users\jenj0>
```

Additionally, the miniconda command prompt window doesn't launch at all.

I tried looking for solutions. For example, I tried [this](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/troubleshooting/#cannot-open-anaconda-prompt-after-installation), but when I try to launch cmd.exe, I see a quick flash of a window opening and then closing and nothing happens.

I have also tried uninstalling/reinstalling miniconda again and had the same issue. I was doing that because I was having issues to run a program. Now I am even further away from solving the problem.

Comment: Did you previously have an installation of anaconda at `C:\Users\jenj0\anaconda3` which is now no longer present

Comment: Yes. I had anaconda installed, then uninstalled it. When I re-installed it, I got the error code I posted above and the anaconda prompt window will no longer open.

Answer (score 2):

There is some invalid paths in the startup scripts for powershell and also the registry keys for `cmd`, stemming from your previous anaconda installation.

You say that you uninstalled anaconda and then installed miniconda, so I am assuming that the path

```
C:\Users\jenj0\anaconda3
```

does not exist and is now

```
C:\Users\jenj0\miniconda3
```

Here is what you do:

1. `Powershell` (from your error message) is trying to read  `C:\Users\jenj0\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\profile.ps1` which contains references to the invalid path. Backup said file and then delete any lines that contain the invalid path
2. `cmd` (and anaconda prompt). Run regedit and then delete the reference to the invalid path in the keys at

```
Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\AutoRun
Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\AutoRun
```